# customizable web services

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap

I would like to implement a aplication that is able to generate a web service on the fly.
That means a user can just select what the ws should do on a mask (it is enough to just return data to a given parameter) and the ws should be generated on the fly without a redeploy.

The type of webservice is not important.
I would like to use java ee together with jboss, but I would also use .NET if it would bring along any advantages.

Is this possible? 
Regrads

Comment: Short answer: it is possible, since you can entirely configure your web application using code. As for how to do this, it would be quite a long answer, for which I would also have to google and test a lot.

Comment: Theres not enough answer in this question to provide a reasonable answer. What kind of web services are we talking about here? SOAP, JAX-WS, JAX-RS? Whats the deployment environment? Note that alot of the modern Java frameworks for web services do not support deployment into a running application. Please expand your question.